# safety of using cocoa's performSelectorOnMainThread thousands of times

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

In my app I have a worker thread which sits around doing a lot of processing. While it's processing, it sends updates to the main thread which uses the information to update GUI elements. This is done with `performSelectorOnMainThread`. For simplicity in the code, there are no restrictions on these updates and they get sent at a high rate (hundreds or thousands per second), and `waitUntilDone` is `false`. The methods called simply take the variable and copy it to a private member of the view controller. Some of them update the GUI directly (because I'm lazy!). Once every few seconds, the worker thread calls `performSelectorOnMainThread` with `waitUntilDone` set to `true` (this is related to saving the output of the current calculation batch).

My question: is this a safe use of `performSelectorOnMainThread`? I ask because I recently encountered a problem where my displayed values stopped updating, despite the background thread continuing to work without issues (and produce the correct output). Since they are fed values this way, I wondered if it might have hit a limit in the number of messages. I already checked the usual suspects (overflows, leaks, etc) and everything's clean. I haven't been able to reproduce the problem, however.

Comment: You might like to consider (1) using `dispatch_async` instead, and (2) not thrashing the main thread with "hundreds or thousands per second" - you should be leaving the main thread open so the user can get stuff done.

Comment: I would suggest looking into `NSNotificationQueue`, it would provide you with a way to notify your main thread to update the GUI, while also allowing you to coalesce many notifications into a single response.

Comment: @matt I know it's bad form to send so many updates. My excuse is that this is an internal app where user interaction is never needed while the processing is ongoing, and that there is no good place to put these updates which will only occur a few times per second (I would have to resort to timers or counters). I'll look into `dispatch_async`, thanks.

Comment: @gaige That looks like exactly what I need, thanks! (I'm still interested in the answer to this question from a theoretical standpoint though!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For simplicity in the code, there are no restrictions on these updates
>   and they get sent at a high rate (hundreds or thousands per second),
>   and waitUntilDone is false.

Yeah.  Don't do that.  Not even for the sake of laziness in an internal only application.

It can cause all kinds of potential problems beyond making the main run loop unresponsive.

Foremost, it will starve your worker thread for CPU cycles as your main thread is constantly spinning trying to update the UI as rapidly as the messages arrive.   Given that drawing is oft done in a secondary thread, this will likely cause yet more thread contention, slowing things down even more.

Secondly, all those messages consume resources.   Potentially lots of them and potentially ones that are relatively scarce, depending on implementation details.

While there shouldn't be a limit, there may likely be a practical limit that, when exceeded, things stop working.   If this is the case, it would be a bug in the system, but one that is unlikely to be fixed beyond a console log that says "Too many messages, too fast, make fewer.".

It may also be a bug in your code, though.   Transfer of state between threads is an area rife with pitfalls.   Are you sure your cross-thread-communication code is bullet proof?  (And, if it is bulletproof, it is quite likely a huge performance cost for your thousands/sec update notifications).

It isn't hard to throttle updates.  While the commented suggestions are all reasonable, it can be done much more easily (NSNotificationQueue is fantastic, but likely overkill unless you are updating the main thread from many different places in your computation).

- create an NSDate whenever you notify the main thread and store date in an ivar
- next time you go to notify main thread, check if more than N seconds have passed
- if they have, update your ivar
- [bonus performance] if all that date comparison is too expensive, consider revisiting your algorithm to move the "update now" trigger to somewhere less frequent.  Barring that, create an int ivar counter and only check the date every N iterations